# Change background color to video on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-video, mouseover

I'm new to video background.

My question is, can I just change color background in each side (right or left side) to video from youtube when I hover each of it side?

So practically, when I hover the left side..orange background will be replace with spesific youtube video, and when I hover to the right side (red background) it will play video (different from the left side) as a background.

I've been searching in the web for hours, but I just can't find the right solution.

here's my code :

```css
.split {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.left {
    left: 0;
    background-color: #E9D94C;
}

.right {
    right: 0;
    background-color: #EA2029;
}

.centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}

.centered img {
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container col-md-10">
  <div class="top-intro" style="position: relative;padding:20px;height:auto;margin:0 auto;font-family: arial;font-size: 12px;z-index: 99999;font-size: 15px;color: #000;text-align: center;border-radius: 10px;top:25px;background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);">
    Lorem ipsum sit amet dolor
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="split left">
    <div class="centered">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar woman">
      <h2>Jane Flex</h2>
      <p>Some text.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="split right">
    <div class="centered">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar2.png" alt="Avatar man">
      <h2>John Doe</h2>
      <p>Some text here too.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here's my full code : http://jsfiddle.net/xkobLdv9/4/

Or I need some kinda javascript thing to do this? will be very grateful if someone can have solution, because I don't understand in javascript thing.

Thanks guys,

Comment: Yes it is possible but you will need javascript (or even better: JQuery) for it

Comment: sadly, i don't understand both of them :( 
can u help me sir @TimGerhard ?

Comment: I posted an answer using css only

Comment: @weBBer i don't understand jquery coding sir, but if u can add/modify jquery code on my previous jsfiddle it will be very help. regards,

Comment: Hi @icaks , I've noticed that your question still hasn't a marked solution. Is this because you simply forgot or is your question still unanswered? I'd be happy to help you further with your case, otherwhise please mark this question as solved as it helps other users for a better experience on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

I made you a small example: hope this helps:
https://jsfiddle.net/pkbxupxc/4/

(Somehow the video does not play in stackoverflow (but it works on jsfiddle).

Basically all I did was put the iframe inside the div, giving it 100% width & height and then setting it display:block on hover and display:none as default.

```css
.hoverMe {
  background: coral;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.hoverMe iframe {
  padding: 0;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.hoverMe:hover iframe.hidden {
  display: block;
}

.foreground {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: rgba (255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<div class="hoverMe">
  <iframe class="hidden" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/avmjunRX_xo" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <div class="foreground">
    <h1>
      Hello World
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks sir...but i have a question, allow="autoplay" it's suppose to auto play the video when we hover it right ? but why your vid example doesn't do autoplay?

Comment: I dont know actually. I just clicked share on youtube and this is the default embed iframe they give you

Comment: okay sir, i'll try to find solution for autoplay problem. many regards,

Comment: You're welcome. You can also use the html <video> tag. Take a look here https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to try this for myself too so I have created exactly what you need using JQuery Here is the link to it [JSFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yrathod101/83064z4b/15/). Just hover over character's face.

```
<div class="container col-md-10">
  <div class="top-intro" style="position: relative;padding:20px;height:auto;margin:0 auto;font-family: arial;font-size: 12px;z-index: 99999;font-size: 15px;color: #000;text-align: center;border-radius: 10px;top:25px;background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);">
    Lorem ipsum sit amet dolor
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="split left">
    <div class="centered">
        <iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/N7ZmPYaXoic" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar woman">
      <h2>Jane Flex</h2>
      <p>Some text.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="split right">
    <div class="centered">
         <iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cKhVupvyhKk" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar2.png" alt="Avatar man">
      <h2>John Doe</h2>
      <p>Some text here too.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.split {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.left {
    left: 0;
    background-color: #E9D94C;
}

.right {
    right: 0;
    background-color: #EA2029;
}

.centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    right: 0;
}

.centered img {
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.centered iframe {
     display: none;
    /* position: absolute; */
    width: 100%;
    /* left: 0; */
    /* right: 0; */
    height: auto;
}
</style>
<script>
$('.split').on('mouseover', function() {
 $(this).find('img').hide();
    $(this).find('iframe').show();
});

$('.split').on('mouseout', function() {
    $(this).find('iframe').hide();
    $(this).find('img').show();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

***This will work for you:***

The below snippet video doesn't play in *StackOverflow* but it works well in fiddle and other pages:

```css
.split {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.left_video,
.right_video {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* overflow-x: hidden; */
  padding: 0px;
  display: none;
  pointer-events:none;
}

.right_video {
  left: auto;
  right: 0px;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
  background-color: #E9D94C;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
  background-color: #EA2029;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.centered img {
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.split:hover+.left_video,
.split:hover+.right_video {
  display: inline-block;
}

.split:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container col-md-10">
  <div class="top-intro" style="position: relative;padding:20px;height:auto;margin:0 auto;font-family: arial;font-size: 12px;z-index: 99999;font-size: 15px;color: #000;text-align: center;border-radius: 10px;top:25px;background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);">
    Lorem ipsum sit amet dolor
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="split left">
    <div class="centered">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar woman">
      <h2>Jane Flex</h2>
      <p>Some text.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <iframe class="left_video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/J5OSRpRyl6g?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <div class="split right">
    <div class="centered">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar2.png" alt="Avatar man">
      <h2>John Doe</h2>
      <p>Some text here too.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <iframe class="right_video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NuIAYHVeFYs?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

> **A working Fiddle with playing video : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jithinrajpr7/xkobLdv9/12/)**

For autoplay the ***iframe video*** I have used: `?autoplay=1` in the last of the youtube URL

*eg: https://www.youtube.com/embed/J5OSRpRyl6g`?autoplay=1`*

Hope this was helpful for you.

Comment: wow sir..u made my day, many thanks sir!
i hope you dont feel disturb if i ask u in the future. have a good day sir :)

Comment: @icaks glad i could help you :), and by the way no need to call *Sir* to anyone here.. All are students.. :)

Comment: @icaks if my code worked for you or any other answer please do mark it as the answer.